# Can't keep linkedlist print function from crashing

Tags: c, linked-list, loops

I have experience in higher level languages, but I'm new to C. I've been given an implementation of a singly linked list. Every time I try to iterate through the list I walk out of memory (at least I assume that's what is happening). Here is the implementation of the list:

```
/*Vertex data type.*/
typedef struct vnode {
   struct vnode *NEXT;
   int DATA;
      } VertexBody;
typedef VertexBody *TypeVertex;

/*List data type (no header, just a pointer to first item).*/
typedef TypeVertex TypeList;
```

Here is my print function:

```
void print_list(TypeList *L) {
    TypeVertex v=*L;
    while(NEXT(v)!=NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", DATA(v));
        v=NEXT(v);
    }
    printf("%d\n", DATA(v));
}
```

Running print_list gives the following output (say the list contains 3 vertices, with data set to 1,2,3 respectively):

```
1
2
3
-94064
```

Then the program crashes. What's the problem?

EDIT: changed "traverse" to "iterate through" in first paragraph.

Comment: It looks as though you didn't initialise the `NEXT` pointer to `NULL` upon construction.

Comment: @DanielFischer So simply declaring something in C doesn't set it to NULL? That would explain a lot.

Comment: No, not in general. Objects with static storage duration are implicitly initialised to 0 if there is no explicit initialisation, automatic stuff (local variables) isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I misidentified the issue. The program was crashing because I had forgotten to allocate memory for the list. I feel like an idiot, but at least I can move on. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

While iterating over the linked list, you want to make sure that the *current* item is not `NULL`. Once you've verified that, you want to print it out, then get the next one.

Hence, this code:

```
void print_list(TypeList *L) {
    TypeVertex v=*L;
    while(NEXT(v)!=NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", DATA(v));
        v=NEXT(v);
    }
    printf("%d\n", DATA(v));
}
```

should be:

```
void print_list(TypeList *L) {
    TypeVertex v=*L;
    while(v!=NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", DATA(v));
        v=NEXT(v);
    }
    printf("%d\n", DATA(v));
}
```

Comment: This is a bug. But this cannot cause a crash with a non-empty list. It'll print all but the last element in the linked list.